# R: How to combine rasters in a loop with all possible combinations?

Tags: r, loops, iteration, combinations, raster

I have three `raster` in a `list`.

```
rasterlist <- (r1, r2, r3)
```

I have one operation to combine each raster with another - let's say add them.

How do I write a `loop` which combines all the rasters iteratively?

Like this:

```
result1 <- r1+r2 
result2 <- r2+r3
result3 <- r1+r3
```

Note: My operation within `{}`is around 200 lines long and not a simple addition, which is why I need a nice loop around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `combn` to get the combination of `list` element and sum them

```
combn(rasterlist, 2, FUN = function(x) x[1] + x[2])
```